# `byoby` exits randomly on autocomplete

Tags: tmux, byobu

For the first time I am having issues with `byobu` existing randomly on autocomplete (when I push <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

I can't reproduce it constantly, but it seems to happen totally randomly.
Where can I find the error message to debug it?

---

I am running the following version:

> `byobu version 5.125`
>
> `tmux 2.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that I had a `set -e` in one of my scripts that is sourced.

That causes the shell to exit by if any commands return a non-zero status [per the definition of `-e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html).
Removing it, solved the issue.

It had nothing to do with `byobu` or `tmux`. Sorry!